# Remove "days 00:00:00"from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, days

So, I have a pandas dataframe with a lot of variables including start/end date of loans. 
I subtract these two in order to get their difference in days.
The result I get is of the type i.e. 349 days 00:00:00.
How can I keep only for example the number 349 from this column?

Comment: Use `df['diff'] = df['diff'].dt.days`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this format,

`df['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['date'], errors='coerce').days`

also, check `.normalize()` function in pandas.